# how you retrieve data from a database

Tags: c#, sql

I have created the classes for the menu items and I cannot figure out how to get a price when someone someone select a pizza from the combobox and selects the toppings. I am getting the pizza prices and the topping price from a database. Here is my pizza Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace ItalianoLIB.BLL
{

   public class Pizza
    {

       public string pizzaName { get; set; }
       public string toppingName { get; set; }
       public double toppingPrice { get; set; }
       public double pizzaPrice { get; set; }



    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;




namespace ItalianoWIN.PLL
{

    public partial class PizzaMenu : Form 
    {
        public string newPizzaName { get; set; }
        public string newToppingName { get; set; }
        public double newToppingPrice { get; set; }
        public double newPizzaPrice { get; set; }

        public PizzaMenu()
        {  

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Pizza_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //new connection from the DButils class
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ItalianoLIB.DLL.DButils.CONSTR);
            con.Open();

            //fill Pizza type combo box
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from pizza", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);



            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
             cboPizzaType.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["PizzaType"]);
            }



            //fill toppings listbox
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Topping",con);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                lstToppings.Items.Add(dt2.Rows[i]["ToppingName"]);
            }



            con.Close();


        }

        private void cboPizzaType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        private void lstToppings_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bnPizOrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newPizzaName = cboPizzaType.Text.ToString();



            //Brings the user back to the main form
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

        private void bnAddTop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            object obj = lstToppings.SelectedItem;
            lstSelTop.Items.Add(obj);
            lstToppings.Items.Remove(obj); 

        }

        private void bnDelTop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object obj = lstSelTop.SelectedItem;
            lstToppings.Items.Add(obj);
            lstSelTop.Items.Remove(obj);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest your writing a small command line program that just interacts with the database, either retrieving something you know is already there, or updating something that is there. It gets trickier trying to insert something.

Comment: What are you actually asking? You are not stating anything that does not work

Comment: I have the pizza table in sql server and it has a pizzaName and a pizzaPrice. I populate the combobox with the pizzaName from the pizza table in sql server.I trying to figure out when someone select a pizza in the combobox, how do i get the price from pizzaPrice field for the selected item.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this here's four

1. Since you've got a DataTable already make it a private field. Then on ComboBox.SelectedIndex change you could retrieve the selected value and then use [`DataTable.Select` or `DataTable.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [Linq To DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) to retrieve the Price value.
2. You could just set the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx), [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx), and [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) properties of the combo box. The DataSource would be the datatable, the display member the Name and the value member the the price. Anytime you want the price you just use the [`ComboBox.SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) (no need to keep a private field in this case because the datasource will hold on to it)
3. You could also use a combination of the above two. For example you could use an ID for the value member you could do a lookup using the techniques described in #1.
4. Still setting the datasource use whatever you want for value member and use the [`DataManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datamanager.aspx) of the combo box and get access to the whole row of the selected item whenever you need it

As an aside many people don't like to use DataTables and perfer using collections of custom classes instead. All of the above will work with with normal collections except you'll be using just Linq or the IEnumerable methods instead of linq to dataset or the datatable methods

Comment: I was able to store the selected pizza in the pizzaName variable <br /> by doing pizzaName =cboPizzaType.SelectedValue.ToString();<br /> but i cannot figure out who to store the price in the pizzaprice variable.

Comment: @PollyPoll I got that from your original question. And my answer describes four ways to do that. Is there something in particular about my answer that you had trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You wanting to do this?

```
private void cboPizzaType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{           
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ItalianoLIB.DLL.DButils.CONSTR);             
con.Open();              
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select PizzaPrice from pizza WHERE PizzaType='" + cboPizzaType.Text + "'", con);             
DataTable dt = new DataTable();             
da.Fill(dt);  
con.Close();           
var oPrice = dt.Rows[0][0];
this.pizzaPrice = (double)oPrice;
}
```

Comment: While this would work it would require a roundtrip to the database every time the combo box changed. That's... less than optimal.